# Hierarchy of span outer background controlling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hierarchy of spans to define different layers of annotations:

```
<span class="eventRel" id="e12-e32">
    <span class="event">
        <span class="hl" id="moh">
            soluzione
            <span style="width:500px;">
                tokenid: 11
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Then I have different controllers, to highlight the token with the background property (in this case: `soluzione`) with different colour.

So, my code is working, just when i have one span layer above the class="hl".

There are the cases that more than 3 spans above the class="hl".

What i do to highlight is:

```
document.getElementById('e12-e32').style.backgroundColor='white';
```

this is working just in case:

```
<span class="event">
    <span class="hl" id="moh">
        soluzione
        <span style="width:500px;">
            tokenid: 11
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And help in this regards!, thanks in advance.

So my need is to apply this style to have the word `soluzione` highlighted:

```
  <span class="eventRel" id="e12-e32" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <span class="event">
        <span class="hl" id="moh">
            soluzione
            <span style="width:500px;">
                tokenid: 11
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. If you want to specifically overwrite the style of the element with the id `moh`, then why not select that element in the first place …?

Comment: So, i found the problem myself, thanks any way!
Here i write what happened, i was trying to highlight the word "soluzione" if that word is participated to an (annotation layer is a span), so the solution is, to give each (annotation layer=span) a class name, and apply the style on the class name, so my wrong implementation was that i used the id to identify the span, then i had duplications on the id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understood your issue but to select all descendents you can use:

```
  document.querySelectorAll(".e12-e32")
```

Answer (score 0):

i applied inline  styles,
    i think the following code may be helpful ..

```
    <span class="event">
    <span class="hl"  style="background-color:yellow;">
        soluzione
        <span style="width:500px;background-color:red;">
            tokenid: 11
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i write what happened, i was trying to highlight the word `soluzione` if that word is participated to an (annotation layer is a span), so the solution is, to give each (annotation layer=span) a class name, and apply the style on the class name, so my wrong implementation was that i used the id to identify the span, then i had duplications on the id.

So always first when you found that some style doesn't work properly, while changing it, check if there are duplication on the id's.
Because there would be any notification of error, and the changes will just apply on the first element have that id!